# How to interpret numerical values of datetime ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I am looking to plot datetime on the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2013,6,24,11,10), dt.datetime(2013,6,24,11,20))
```

This would generate a plot with datetime values (e.g., 11:13 rather than some numerical number) on the x-axis.

However, when I try to get the xtick values from the plot using

`ax.get_xticks()`

it returns

```
array([15880.46527778, 15880.46597222, 15880.46666667, 15880.46736111,
       15880.46805556, 15880.46875   , 15880.46944444, 15880.47013889,
       15880.47083333, 15880.47152778, 15880.47222222])
```

Can someone please explain what these numbers mean, so I can interpret them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format). Matplotlib uses as timestamp the number of *days* since epoch, not seconds, as you could be used to. You can use the functions from `matplotlib.dates` for conversions and interpretation.

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mpldate
mpldate.date2num(dt.datetime(2013,6,24,11,10)) # 15880.465277777777
mpldate.num2date(ax.get_xticks())
# [datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 12, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 16, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
# datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 11, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]
```